# return x amount of each group in rails by has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm a rails newbie so pardon if this is a basic question.I extended domain model by has_many

```
has_many :stream_filters


has_many :active_filters,
               -> { where(active: true) },
               through: :stream_filters,
               source: :filter,
               class_name: 'Filter'

has_many :results,
           -> { distinct },
           through: :active_filters

has_many :latest_results,
           -> { distinct.order('created_at DESC').limit(30) },
           source: :results,
           through: :active_filters
```

as you can see in latest_result I get only 30 of them.

Now is there a way to group them by a property and take 30 of each group?

I tried this code but it's not working, it's return one of each group

```
has_many :latest_results,
           -> { distinct.group("source_id").order('created_at DESC').limit(30) },
           source: :results,
           through: :active_filters
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
latest_results.all.group_by(&:source_id).map! { |source_id, latest_results_of_source| latest_results_of_source.limit(30) }
```

or

```
has_many :latest_results, -> { all.group_by(&:source_id).map! { |source_id, latest_results_of_source| latest_results_of_source.limit(30) } }, source: :results, through: :active_filters
```

Comment: it says ArgumentError: Unknown key: 1. Valid keys are: :includes, :eager_load, :preload, :select, :group, :order, :joins, :left_joins, :left_outer_joins, :references, :extending, :unscope, :limit, :offset, :lock, :readonly, :reordering, :reverse_order, :distinct, :create_with, :where, :having, :from

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `map!' for #<Hash:0x007f911b7ce968>
Did you mean?  map

Comment: I tried map now NoMethodError: undefined method `limit' for #<Array:0x007f911dd3ddc0>

Comment: and without limit it returns 4 record , one record per each group